# Why would I get a "This connection is not private" certificate error from https://www.whatever.com when https://whatever.com works just fine?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

I got a proper signed certificate for one of my domains today, analyticalengine.com. I have run into problems stemming from the fact that while

https://analyticalengine.com

works fine,

https://www.analyticalengine.com

throws up a "This Connection is Not Private: This website may be impersonating "www.analyticalengine.com" to steal your financial information." warning. Do I really need to get a separate certificate for this?

Comment: It depends where you get the certificate. They're separate certificates, though most hosting companies will give you both the WWW and non-WWW equivalent at the same time. LetsEncrypt is wildcard certificates, which won't work in this regard.

Comment: Just add both FQDNs as SAN values and you’d be fine